# How to grow width of an element to fit window's width?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to show an image in a `WebBrowser`

```
<html>
    <body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;border:0px">
        <img src="http://phaseoneimageprofessor.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/logo_image_professor_22.jpg"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want width of `image` grow and be the same as width of visible window (it's not full screen). it's height should grow too without loosing its shape.

```
var htmlString = "<html><body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;border:0px"><img src="http://phaseoneimageprofessor.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/logo_image_professor_22.jpg"/></body></html>"; //It's missing some backslashes, you got the idea.
webBrowser.NavigateToString(htmlString);
```

currently it just appears at the corner of the page, and this is not what I want.

How can I achieve that? thanks.

Comment: Add `width="100%"` to image and dont set width anywere else like body etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img src="image.jpg" width="100%" />
```

By default in HTML if you specify either height OR width (but not both) for an image, the other attribute will be scaled automatically to keep the same aspect ratio.